# JavaScript - access to properties after (closure).bind()

Tags: javascript

I've constructed a rather useful function to identify data-types; however, while coding happily I was rudely interrupted with a rather worrying dilemma.

As you may know, after calling `.bind({foo:'bar'})` on a closure, you cannot access said `foo` property "externally"; however, inside the closure, `this.foo` works.

Also, when assigning something in such a way, you often face a throw: `intermediary ... blah blah is undefined` when you try access a property - directly after defining it. The code below fixes these issues but...

The problem is explained after the code:

```js
"use strict";

if ('undefined' == typeof global)
{
    Object.defineProperty
    (
        window,'global',
        {
            writable:false,
            configurable:false,
            enumerable:false,
            value:window
        }
    );
}


Object.defineProperty
(
    Function.prototype, 'wrap',
    {
        writable:false,
        enumerable:false,
        configurable:false,

        value:function(jsob)
        {
            this.bind(jsob);

            for (var i in jsob)
            { this[i] = jsob[i]; }

            return this;
        }
    }
);


global.typeOf = function(data)
{
    if ((data === null) || (data === undefined))
    { return 'void'; }

    if ((data === true) || (data === false))
    { return 'bool'; }

    var tpof = (({}).toString.call(data).match(/\s([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase());

    if ((tpof == 'array') || (tpof == 'htmlcollection') || (tpof == 'namednodemap'))
    { return 'list'; }

    if ((tpof == 'global') || (tpof == 'window'))
    { return 'glob'; }

    switch (tpof.substr(0,6))
    {
        case 'number': return 'unit';
        case 'string': return (/[^\x20-\x7E\t\r\n]/.test(data) ? 'blob' : 'text');
        case 'object': return 'jsob';
        case 'functi': return 'func';

        default: return 'node';
    }
}
.wrap
({
    list:'void bool unit text blob list jsob func node glob'.split(' '),
    init:function()
    {
        this.list.forEach(function(item)
        {
            global[(item.toUpperCase())] = item;
            global[('is'+(item[0].toUpperCase() + item.substr(1,item.length)))] = function(data)
            {
                return ((typeOf(data) == this.text) ? true : false);
            }
            .bind({text:item.toLowerCase()}); // <-- ISSUE
        });

        return this;
    }
}).init();
```

So the little `wrapper` above takes care of such weirdness; however, have a look on the line where `<-- ISSUE` is; see, I cannot use `wrap()` there, I have to use `bind()`, else - inside the function - `this` is undefined!!

Let me clarify: If you use the entire code just as it is above in `<script>` tags inside a brand-spanking-new html file; just change that `ISSUE` line's `bind` word to: `wrap`; then try something like: `isText("bite me!");`

You will see an error that specifies something like:

> **cannot read property "text" from undefined ..**

so; if you do a `console.log(this)` inside that function definition there; you will see `undefined`.

If anyone could help fixing this, or at least explain why this is happening, I'd really appreciate the input.

Comment: @Kashif :: The `wrap()` method makes it possible to access properties -external from the closure. It shortens the code needed also.

Comment: @deceze :: all the code may be part of the issue; and - the code is usable just as it is, just copy+paste & test; nothing is "missing" at all.

Comment: Seems like the problem you're running into is the same as the one you're trying to fix.  The wrapped isX functions cannot access `this` from the wrapped closure.  I suspect you're in effect asking for an explanation of your "wierdness"

Comment: @Tibrogargan :: haha, well spotted, but, still though, can **this** be fixed? I mean, by **this** being _undefined_ in its own scope - or to specify its scope rather.

Comment: @argon Maybe you could explicitly specifiy it somehow - but I have no idea, I'm out of my depth

Comment: I think you did not understand how `bind` works. That `this.bind(jsob);` call does not make any sense, as you are not using its result. Also it doesn't have anything to do with closures.

Comment: WTH are you using this `wrap` thing at all? In the example you've shown, the same result could much more easily have been achieved without a custom Function method.

Comment: @Bergi :: If that could fix the issue, by all means, your answer would be appreciated ;)

Comment: Whatever else you are trying to do here, it is certain that `this.bind(jsob);` is a NO-OP. Also, you are misusing the word "closure"--you seem to be using it to just refer to a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see absolutely no purpose for this `wrap` function. In fact there's no reason to use `this` or `bind` at all for this use case. Just do

```
global.typeOf = function(data) {
    if (data == null) return 'void';
    switch (typeof data)
        case "boolean": return 'bool';
        case "number": return 'unit';
        case "string": return /[^\x20-\x7E\t\r\n]/.test(data) ? 'blob' : 'text';
    }
    switch (Object.prototype.toString.call(data).slice(8, -1).toLowerCase()) {
        case "array":
        case "htmlcollection":
        case "namednodemap": return 'list';
        case "global":
        case "window": return 'glob';
        case "object": return 'jsob';
        case "function": return 'func';
        default: return 'node';
    }
};
global.typeOf.list = 'void bool unit text blob list jsob func node glob'.split(' ');

global.typeOf.list.forEach(function(item) {
    global[item.toUpperCase()] = item;
    global['is'+item[0].toUpperCase()+item.slice(1)] = function(data) {
        return typeOf(data) == item;
    }
});
```

Comment: The point of the "bind" (wrap) is that the list of primary types should be contained in a place where it belongs, because I also have another function: "kindOf" - which checks for secondary datatypes and it needs a reference from which to name and define constants and functions accordingly. It can be done by just assigning it after, but I'm looking for a way to assign it once, without having to re-reference "typeOf" outside of it's own scope while defining it.  This is because these globals should be immutable after they are defined; the code is longer lol, this is the short version :)

Comment: If you can merge that list with the typeOf closure, in such a way that it can be accessed like: `console.log(typeOf.list)` -- and if your code works in NodeJS also, then I'll gladly accept it.  The problem that I have with your current "isFunc" assignment is that the comparison checks for a variable "item" that may not exist in scope at a time the "isFunc" is called, hence, that is also the reason for "bind" as it contains its own value.

Comment: Found some interesting posts on "lexical scope" as you used it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures  and .. here: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/20/javascript-scope-closures/ .... it could cause problems if not carefully used though... have a look here: https://www.toptal.com/javascript/10-most-common-javascript-mistakes

Comment: Anyway, I'm sold, it works, thanks for participating :)

Comment: "*without having to re-reference "typeOf" outside of it's own scope while defining it, because these globals should be immutable*" doesn't make any sense. You can create an immutable global value, and nothing keeps you from referencing it afterwards (that's actually their whole purpose)

Comment: "*The problem with your current "isFunc" assignment is that the comparison checks for a variable "item" that may not exist in scope at a time the "isFunc" is called*" is rubbish (sorry for the harsh words). This is exactly what [closures](http://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/1048572) are good for.

Comment: I meant to say that once it is defined in one statement (i.e. no semi-colon in between statements) - it should be "frozen" and not be changed or deleted by any other code. Trying to establish a strict code policy and ways to work that would reduce creation of bugs, or instability.

Comment: At the "rubbish" comment, ya, I saw that as I was researching on this. It's great that it's working everywhere now as a standard for some years lol, I guess I didn't get the memo :D

Comment: @argon: You can put an `Object.freeze(global.typeoOf)` after the last of the statements that create the object :-) Or otherwise use an IIFE to wrap it in a clear building block (like a module). Or if you really want to use a custom `wrap` function, just let it extend the object with properties, but I still don't see a reason to `bind` it to anything. Regardless, that `init` thing as a method should be avoided.

Comment: Thanks for the update, see, that's what I'm trying to eliminate: **duplication** ... in your updated code: `global.typeOf` is referenced 3 times. It can be done 1 time, if you use that `wrap` thingy-mabob

Comment: :: yep, I use "Object.freeze", lol, even made a "deepfreeze" :D

Comment: I think you really should have a look at the various kinds of module patterns then (none of which need a `wrap` thingy). Especially helpful if you actually don't need the `list` to be available globally, but rather only in multiple functions (`kindOf` etc).

Comment: Good points, thanks, I'll look into it. Right now I'm trying to establish a small yet powerful starting-point as 1 JS file that could be shared cross platform (browser + nodejs), anyway.. thanks for the great advice.